# Maximum likelihood estimator for variance vs unbiased estimator for variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, estimators

I am having trouble understanding the advantages to using the MLE vs the unbiased estimator for variance. If I have data that includes a small number of extreme outliers, which estimator would be better? Also if I have a small sample size that doesn't include extreme outliers, which estimator would be better? Thank you to anyone who is able to help clear this up for me.

Comment: What distribution are you working with?  The MLE will be different depending upon the (assumed) distribution of the data, and consequently so will it's characteristics.

Comment: I'm not sure if this explanation will help. But I am sampling from a population of people with random ages from 1 - 70. I am then comparing the variance of the overall population, to the max likelihood estimator for variance taken from the sample size.

Comment: When you say "max likelihood estimator", that assumes you have a likelihood function you are maximizing... what would that be?